# SFML set the same size to multiple shapes

Tags: c++, graphics, drawing, sfml

I have a vector of **sf::RectangleShape**. I want all the rectangles to have the same size. I create rectangles with the following loop :

```
std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> rectangles;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sf::RectangleShape r(sf::Vector2f(200,100));
    r.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
    r.setOutlineThickness(1);
    r.setPosition(i*WEIGHT_RECTANGLE, 0);
    r.setFillColor(sf::Color(150, 50, 250));
    rectangles.push_back(r);
}
```

> My problem is that the size only applies for the last rectangle. See :
>   [image: Size only applying for the last rectangle]

The position of the shape works well.

I also tried to create a new sf::Vector2f and use the setSize function like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sf::RectangleShape r;
    sf::Vector2f size(200, 100);
    r.setSize(size)
    r.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
    r.setOutlineThickness(1);
    r.setPosition(i*WEIGHT_RECTANGLE, 0);
    r.setFillColor(sf::Color(150, 50, 250));
    rectangles.push_back(r);
}
```

But I have the same result.

Thanks for your help!

btw im using Visual Studio 17 with the last SFML version

Comment: What is `WEIGHT_RECTANGLE`?

Comment: Judging from your picture all the rectangles have the right size. They overlap so you can only see the last one fully.

Comment: Indeed the problem was the position of the rectangle (they overlap as you said). Problem solved, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try any code, but based on the image, I'm pretty sure that you're overlapping those rectangles.

The gap between rectangles is determined by this sentence:

`r.setPosition(i*WEIGHT_RECTANGLE, 0);`

I assume your `WEIGHT_RECTANGLE` (maybe you mean `WIDTH_RECTANGLE`) now have a small value, about 10 or 20 pixel probably.

You should space each rectangle having in mind the width of the rectangle itself, something like:

`r.setPosition(i*(WIDTH_RECTANGLE + GAP), 0);`

Where `GAP` is the actual clearance between rectangles.